# Restricted product metric.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

**Some Facts**

Let $\{(X_n,d_n)\}$ be a sequence of metric spaces. If $\sum diam(X_i)<\infty,$
then the metric $\gamma$ given by
$$
\gamma(x,y)=\sum \dfrac{1}{2^n}d_n(x_n,y_n)
$$
provides a metric to the product space $\prod X_n$ which is 
equivalent to the product topology.

On the other hand if the metrics spaces $X_n$ are not bounded we just consider the metric 
$$
\rho(x,y)=\sum \dfrac{1}{2^n}\dfrac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}
$$
which is also equivalent to the product topology of $X$.

**Question**

Consider the family  of metric spaces 
 $(X_n,d_n)=(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ and $(Y_n,d_n)=([-k,k],|\cdot|)$
where $|\cdot|$ denote the absolute value. We will consider in 
$X=\prod_{n} \mathbb{R}$ the metric  given by product metric given 
above by $\rho$, and we will consider in $Y=\prod_{n}[-k,k]$ the metric
given above by $\gamma$.

My question is the following: Is the metric $\gamma$ generate the same topology as the metric $\overline{\rho},$ which consists of the restriction 
of $\rho$ to the subspace $Y$?

Comment: Perhaps I am totally mistaken, but that metric does not seem to give the product topology; it seems to give something more akin to the box topology.

Comment: $\rho(x,y)$ should have $d_n(x_n, y_n)$ in the nominator too, I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are  absolutely right! Thanks